# Function returns bad value inside of a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have two functions that return the good value. But when I call those functions inside of a trigger they always returns 0 instead of the good value.

The return type of those functions is `real`. The direct and dramatic consequence is that the trigger inserts wrong values in tables when it is called.

The function:

```
create or replace function get_remaining_hour(id_user_v integer,id_absence_v_type integer,id_year_v integer) returns real as
$BODY$
BEGIN
    return (select sum(number_hour) 
            from remaining_absence_day 
            where id_user= $1 
              and id_absence_type=$2 
              and id_year=$3 );
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

The trigger function (modified for testing!):

```
create  OR REPLACE  function update_absence() returns TRIGGER  AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  old_number_hour real;
BEGIN
  old_number_hour:=get_remaining_hour(3,2,8);
  insert into debugging(col,val) values('old_number_hour', old_number_hour);
  return null;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

The trigger definition:

```
drop trigger if exists update_absence on absence;
CREATE  TRIGGER update_absence
    after update of type,duration_hour,duration_day on absence
    for each ROW
    execute procedure update_absence();
```

Comment: Without any code : no.

Comment: I have add an extract from the code i'm using.

Comment: You are not changing anything in the trigger function. You are only assigning that value to a local variable, but you do not change the `NEW` record.

Comment: Your trigger does nothing. What is a purpose of assignment to `old_number_hour`? This variable is not visible outside the function.

Comment: it's an extract of the code, the part wich is not functionnal.
When i use old_number_hour to update or insert in  any table from the trigger the result is always 0.

Comment: In fact, the value of old_number_hour is used with two othe variable to caculate the to putt in a field of table

Comment: The trigger function as shown will **never** change anything in the database. You need to show us the **complete** code.

Comment: i have add in the code an exemple wheni use the function to insert into a table

Comment: Are you saying that you don't see the correct values in the table `debugging`?

Comment: yes instead of the correct for five or 6 the only value i see in the table debugging is 0.

Comment: Please *always* provide your version of Postgres.

Comment: my version is 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presented code should work.

It is particularly odd that you see ***`0`*** as result. If no matching row is found in `remaining_absence_day`, you would see `NULL`, not `0`. But if you call the function with the same parameters in the same environment you should see the same result to begin with.

The remaining possible explanation I can think of: confusion with the **schema search path**. Like: you have a second instance of the function `get_remaining_hour()` or the table `remaining_absence_day` in a different schema. And you call the function with a different setting for `search_path`.
Did you run your comparison in the same session?

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Or, since you work with an `AFTER` trigger: there might be **other triggers** on table `absence` that modify the table `remaining_absence_day`, which are fired *before* your trigger.

*All other modifications I made are of cosmetic nature or minor simplifications*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_remaining_hour(id_user_v int
                                            , id_absence_v_type int
                                            , id_year_v int)
  RETURNS real AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN (
   SELECT sum(number_hour) 
   FROM   remaining_absence_day  -- referencing the right table? see search_path
   WHERE  id_user         = $1 
   AND    id_absence_type = $2 
   AND    id_year         = $3
   );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;  -- don't quote the language name

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_absence()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN   
   INSERT INTO debugging(col, val)
   VALUES('old_number_hour', get_remaining_hour(3,2,8));  -- hard coded only for testing?
   RETURN null;  -- only good for AFTER trigger
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_absence ON absence;
CREATE TRIGGER update_absence
AFTER UPDATE OF type, duration_hour, duration_day ON absence
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_absence();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right when you said:
"Or, since you work with an AFTER trigger: there might be other triggers on table absence that modify the table remaining_absence_day, which are fired before your trigger."

There was e trigger fired on table debugging which interfered with my new trigger.

Thank you everbody for your help.